# Angular 5/4/2 method passed as reference is not in scope

Tags: angular

[Run the entire example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yjvto4?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

I have a simple module that I call it as the following:

```
<app-button [(registerOnClickEvent)]="alertTest" ></app-button>
```

The module is listening internally to click event and passit outside, to `alertTest`:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-button',
  template: '<button (click)="passTheClickEvent($event)"  value="test"  >Click</button>',
})
export class ButtonComponent    {
  @Input() 
  registerOnClickEvent : Function = new Function();

  passTheClickEvent(){
    this.registerOnClickEvent();
  }
}
```

inside `alertTest`, the `appModel` is undefined:

```
export class AppComponent  {
  appModel : AppModel = {name : "Ron Howard"};
  alertTest(){
    console.log(this.appModel); // this.appModel us undefined
    alert("test");
  }
}
```

I dont understand why? I am initiating it:

`appModel : AppModel = {name : "Ron Howard"};`

[Run the entire example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yjvto4?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use arrow function to achieve this

Working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hbfhxu?file=app/app.component.ts

```
export class AppComponent  {
   appModel : AppModel = {name : "Ron Howard"};

   // convert the function into arrow function
   alertTest = () => {
      console.log(this.appModel);
      alert(this.appModel);
   }
}
```

To know more on Arrow function, here is the [mozilla documentation link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

> An arrow function expression has a shorter syntax than a function
>   expression and does not have its own this, arguments, super, or
>   new.target. These function expressions are best suited for non-method
>   functions, and they cannot be used as constructors.
>
> Until arrow functions, every new function defined its own this value
>   (a new object in the case of a constructor, undefined in strict mode
>   function calls, the base object if the function is called as an
>   "object method", etc.). This proved to be less than ideal with an
>   object-oriented style of programming.

Comment: I did not know you could do it like this. I have always bound the scope of the component to the function. This method is much easier and cleaner. Thanks for the enlightenment and +1 for the Mozilla documentation link.

Answer (score 3):

@Paritosh's answer is correct and I recommend doing it like that. I just want to propse yet another (older?) method of doing it. The scope for `this` is different when you pass the function like that to another component.

You could bind the scope from AppComponent to the method like this:

```
export class AppComponent  {
  appModel : AppModel = {name : "Ron Howard"};
  // bind scope from AppCompoent to the method, making this being the scope from this component, and not from ButtonComponent 
  alertTestScoped:Function = this.alertTest.bind(this); 
  alertTest(){
    console.log(this.appModel); // this.appModel us undefined
    alert("test");
  }

}
```

and then pass `alertTestScoped` to the `AppButton` component.

[Working example](https://angular-5x9jnt.stackblitz.io)

Comment: The binding thing you are mentioning, `arrow` function does kind of that thing only. If your are using `typescript` then you should use this as best practices. else there is no use of working with latest technologies.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I am aware of arrow functions (mainly how they are used when working with `Observers`), but I was not aware you could do it like you did in your answer when it comes to passing functions to other components, so I am glad I came across this question and your answer.

Comment: haha, BTW, TBO, I came to know about this yesterday only, one of the contributor of ngx-datatable suggested me about this on [GitHub](https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-datatable/issues/1253)