# this.myArrayVariable is undefined in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, socket.io

I am implementing a socke.io chat application in angular 4. I have an array that represents the messages that the user receives, I am having a hard time updating this array, I can't seem to reference it.

```
@Component({
    .....
})
export class JanelaChatComponent implements OnInit {
    mensagens: MensagemChat[];
    ngOnInit() {
        this.socket.on("update", function (msg) {
            this.mensagens.push(new MensagemChat(msg)); // this.mensagens is undefined here
        });
    }
}
```

The error occurs when I receive a message and try to push the message into the array by creating a new instance of my model (MensagemChat). I am using the package ngx-socket-io.

Comment: `mensagens: MensagemChat[] = []` ?

Comment: @Striped I don't know if your code works without arrow function but your initialization was something that was missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using `typescript`, use `arrow` function.

```
this.socket.on("update", (msg) => { 
      this.mensagens.push(new MensagemChat(msg)); // this.mensagens is undefined here
});
```

That will bind your controller's scope with the `function(msg)` part, and you'll be able to access it inside your function, where you are doing `this.mensagens.push...`

For more reference on **[Arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)**

Look at this answer [Angular 5/4/2 method passed as reference is not in scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48557364/angular-5-4-2-method-passed-as-reference-is-not-in-scope/48557480#48557480)
 which is also having the similar situation.

----UPDATE----

First of all, you need to initialise your array :)

```
export class JanelaChatComponent implements OnInit {
  mensagens: MensagemChat[];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.mensagens = [];

    this.socket.on("update", function (msg) {
        this.mensagens.push(new MensagemChat(msg)); // this.mensagens is undefined here
    });
  } 
}
```

Comment: I'm still getting _this.mensagens is undefined.

Comment: got it, updated the answer. so silly mistake you did :) its ok

Comment: Worked! I am not saying that I don't need to learn more about Typescript, and that an initialization doesn't make sense, much less that Typescript isn't awesome because it is, but I didn't expected to have to write this.mensagens = [].

Answer (score 0):

Fat arrow function is the solution use below snippet

@Component({ ..... }) export class JanelaChatComponent implements OnInit { mensagens: MensagemChat[]; ngOnInit() { this.socket.on("update", (msg) => { this.mensagens.push(new MensagemChat(msg)); // this.mensagens is undefined here }); } }