# Unable to execute function in Context Menu

Tags: angular, typescript, ag-grid

I'm trying to call a function in my context menu.

```
getContextMenuItems(params) {
    console.log(params.node.data)
    var result = [

      {
        name: "Delete",
        action : function () { 
         this.deletePriceFactor(params.node.data);
        }
        ,
        cssClasses: ["redFont", "bold"]
      },
      {
        name: "Audit"
      }

    ]
      return result;
    }

 deletePriceFactor = (rowdata)  =>{
    this.priceFactorService.deleteEntry(rowdata.exchangeCode, rowdata.productCode, rowdata.secType).subscribe(pricefactors => {
    });

  }
```

I keep getting an error: 
ERROR TypeError: this.deletePriceFactor is not a function
    at Object.action (price-factor.component.ts:162)

I have tried using arrow functions like this:

```
action : () =>  { 
         this.deletePriceFactor(params.node.data);
        }
```

The above results in another error: core.js:1673 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'deletePriceFactor' of undefined

Comment: what is Object.action  ?

Comment: var result is a list of objects. Action is a key in that obect that calls my function

Comment: In the first version it won't work, ` function() {}` change the context of this

Comment: how would i change the context of this?

Comment: can you add a jsfiddle ou stackblitz code ? i'll simple to test

Comment: try to modify the signature `deletePriceFactor` to `deletePriceFactor(rowdata) {}`

Comment: that gives me core.js:1673 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'deletePriceFactor' of undefined

Answer (score 10, accepted):

if your html is like:

```
<ag-grid-angular
      [getContextMenuItems]="getContextMenuItems"
      .
      .
      .
    ></ag-grid-angular>
```

then the function `getContextMenuItems` must be writen like :

```js
getContextMenuItems = (params) => {
}
```

Hence, the `this` keyword points to your component.

After that, call your method like:

```js
action : () => this.deletePriceFactor(params.node.data)
```

Comment: This is a great insight. Thanks.

Comment: Super explaination of "this" keyword, I was having the same problem. thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can add the reference to this in grid's context -

```
this.gridOptions.context = {
                    thisComponent : this
                };
```

And then, thisComponent can be access as below -

```
private getContextMenuItems(params) { 
    console.log(params);
    var result = [
        { // custom item
            name: 'Sample',
            action: function () { params.context.thisComponent.callMe(); },
            icon: '<i class="fa fa-pencil" />'
        }];
    return result;
}
```

Same can be done for any other call backs like cellRenderer.

reference: [Scoping issues while using context menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42680019/scoping-issues-while-using-context-menu)

Its worked for me

Comment: why do you think icon is not displaying ? thanks