# Ag-grid context menu icon

Tags: ag-grid-react

Is it possible to add custom HTML elements to an icon to an Ag-grid context menu item?  The following doesnt render any icon:

```
 getContextMenuItems = (params) => [
    {
      name: 'Cancel items',
      action: this.onCancelLocates(),
      icon:  <span><Icon name="cancel" size="small" /></span>
    },
    'separator',
    'copy',
    'copyWithHeaders',
    'paste',
    'separator',
    'export'
  ]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to execute function in Context Menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56838691/unable-to-execute-function-in-context-menu)

Comment: That link also did not work, may be because of not having appropriate framework css import.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can add custome icons

```
 getContextMenuItems = (params) => [
{
  name: 'Cancel items',
  action: this.onCancelLocates(),
  icon:  '<span class="ag-icon ag-icon-save" unselectable="on" role="presentation"></span>'
},
'separator',
'copy',
'copyWithHeaders',
'paste',
'separator',
'export'  ]
```

You can get this span code from right clicking the already present icons inside the context menu.
Thanks