# Can't pass angular function to menu item

Tags: angular, ag-grid

Getting familiar with Ag-Grid and caught one problem that I can't pass angular function into menu item cause I assume it gets executed in another scope.

I did assign property for grid as in a tutorial like:
[getContextMenuItems]="getContextMenuItems"

And tried to pass angular function to be executed on context menu item click

My angular code looks like this:

```
 public getContextMenuItems(params: GetContextMenuItemsParams) {
    const items: Array<MenuItemDef> = [{
      name: 'test',
      action: () => { this.a() }
    }];

    return items;
  }

  public a () {
    console.log("test")
  }
```

Expected output: Should console log out "test" on menu click

Actual output: Cannot read property 'a' of undefined

Comment: This seemed to be relevant with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42680019/scoping-issues-while-using-context-menu

Answer (score 0):

Loosely speaking, the function `getContextMenuItems` is executed in an ag-Grid *context* (not Angular), and hence `this` will *not* be your component. (In my version of ag-Grid here, `this` is `undefined`.)

Your options are

1. use the **grid context**. Assign it a reference to the (grid's parent-) component and access it in `getContextMenuItems(params: GetContextMenuItemsParams)` as `params.context`

or

2. define `getContextMenuItems` using **fat arrow syntax** as pointed out by Seeschorle and others [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68175264/197574): `getContextMenuItems = (params) => { /*...*/ }`