# Ag Grid Angular Context Menu calling function

Tags: angular, ag-grid-angular

Unable to call a function from Context Menu items in AG Grid Angular, here is my high level code

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getContextMenuItems = (params) => this.getMenuItems(params);
  }

  deleteMenuItemEvent = (rowdata) => {
    window.alert("Test Test");
  };

 getMenuItems(
    params: GetContextMenuItemsParams
  ): (string | MenuItemDef)[] {
   
    var result: (string | MenuItemDef)[] = [
      {
        // custom item
        name: "Menu Item 1",
        action: () => this.deleteMenuItemEvent(params),
        cssClasses: ['red', 'bold'],
      },
      {
        // custom item
        name: "Menu Item 2",
        action: function () {
          this.deleteMenuItemEvent(params);
        }
      }
    ];
    return result;
  }
```

Getting the below error

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'deleteMenuItemEvent')
```

Tried the options from below url but no luck, is there any thing else to be done

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42680019/scoping-issues-while-using-context-menu][1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `.bind(this)` to ensure the function always executes on the component context!

[Function.prototype.bind Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getContextMenuItems = (params) => this.getMenuItems(params);
  }

  deleteMenuItemEvent = (params) => {
    const rowData = params.node.data;
    window.alert("Test Test");
  };

 getMenuItems(
    params: GetContextMenuItemsParams
  ): (string | MenuItemDef)[] {
   
    var result: (string | MenuItemDef)[] = [
      {
        // custom item
        name: "Menu Item 1",
        action: this.deleteMenuItemEvent.bind(this), // tells js to execute on the context of 
        // this component where deleteMenuItemEvent method exists!
        cssClasses: ['red', 'bold'],
      },
      {
        // custom item
        name: "Menu Item 2",
        action: this.deleteMenuItemEvent.bind(this), // tells js to execute on the context of 
        // this component where deleteMenuItemEvent method exists!
      }
    ];
    return result;
  }
```

Comment: Would you still need the bind method on the `this.deleteMenuitemEvent` as well? The method is expecting a `rowData` parameter but the current implementation doesn't seem to provided it.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the `bind` syntax directly on the template like this.

```html
<ag-grid-angular
...
    [getContextMenuItems]="getMenuItems.bind(this)"
  ></ag-grid-angular>
```